# manipulating strings, search text

Tags: c#, search, string

Note 1: I only have strings, not files, ONLY strings.

I have a string like this (NOTE: I'll include line numbers for clarity)

The line separator is `\r\n` (CRLF)

```
string allText = 

1 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum

2 == START 001partXXX.sql ==

3 Lorem ipsum TEXT Lorem ipsum

4 == END 001partXXX.sql ==

5 Lorem ipsum TEXT Lorem ipsum

6 == START 002partzzz.sql ==

7 Lorem ipsum TEXT Lorem ipsum

8 == END 002partzzz.sql ==
```

I have `contents` strings like this:

```
string contents1 =
== START 001partXXX.sql ==

Lorem ipsum TEXT Lorem ipsum

== END 001partXXX.sql ==
```

The other `contents` string:

```
string contents2 =

== START 002partzzz.sql ==

Lorem ipsum TEXT Lorem ipsum

== END 002partzzz.sql ==
```

Then,

```
allText.IndexOf(contents1) != -1

allText.IndexOf(contents2) != -1
```

I need a function that receives 3 parameters: `allText`, `Contents`, and `text` to find in `contents`, and return the line number of `Text` to find in `AllText`.

For example,

> input: allText, contents2, "TEXT"
>
> ouput = line number 7

Another sample,

> input: allText, contents1, "TEXT"
>
> ouput = line number 3

Another sample,

> input: allText, contents1, "TEXT NOT FOUND"
>
> ouput = line number -1

How can I implement this function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when TextToFind isn't found?  Also, your lines, how are they separated? \r, \r\n or \n?

Comment: I'm only using the files as a way to seed the strings passed to the function.  The function itself only deals with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite confusing, but I think I got the gist of it.  I would edit the question, but I don't have the rep to do so.

To recap, you have a string that contains the contents of multiple files.  You want to know the index of a particular bit of text from one of the individual files in the larger master file.

This will return -1 when the text isn't found.  I also assume the lines in your strings are separated by whatever the platform default is (\r\n on windows).

Hope this answers your question.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //read relevant text from disk
        string AllText = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\alltext.txt"); 
        string Contents = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\contents.txt");
        string text = "TEXT";

        int line = SearchForLine(AllText, Contents, text);

        Console.WriteLine(line);
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int SearchForLine(string AllText, string Contents, string SearchText)
    {
        //split strings into arrays based on newline character 
        //uses environment.newline (\r\n on windows). change to what you 
        //need if this isn't correct
        string[] AllTextSplit = SplitStringOnNewLine(AllText);
        string[] ContentsSplit = SplitStringOnNewLine(Contents);

        //find the first line of Contents in AllText 
        int start = FindIndex(AllTextSplit, ContentsSplit[0]);
        //find the last line of Contents in AllText 
        int stop = FindIndex(AllTextSplit, ContentsSplit[ContentsSplit.Length - 1]);

        //search alltext for SearchText between start and stop (lines where contents exist in AllText
        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++)
        {
            if (AllTextSplit[i].IndexOf(SearchText)!=-1)
            {
                return i + 1; // + 1 because you want line numbers starting at 1   
            }
        }
       return -1; 
    }

    private static int FindIndex(string[] TextToSearch, string SearchText)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TextToSearch.Length; i++)
        {
            if (TextToSearch[i] == SearchText)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    private static string[] SplitStringOnNewLine(string StringToSplit)
    {
        return StringToSplit.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
                       StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
}
```